# HashSet<POJO>.contains misbehaves

Tags: java, hadoop, hashset, mapper

As part of a Hadoop `Mapper`, I have a `HashSet<MySimpleObject>` that contains instances of a very simple class with only two integer attributes.  As one should, I customised `hashCode()` and `equals()`:

```
public class MySimpleObject {

  private int i1, i2;

  public set(int i1, int i2) {
    this.i1 = i1;
    this.i2 = i2;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + i1;
    result = prime * result + i2;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if ( obj.getClass() != MySimpleObject.class ) return false;

    MySimpleObject other = (MySimpleObject)obj;
    return (this.i1 == other.i1) && (this.i2 == other.i2);
  }
```

**Somehow, sometimes, calls to `mySet.contains(aSimpleObj)` return `true` though the set actually doesn't contain this value.**

I understand how `hashCode()` is first used to  split instances into buckets and `equals()` only called to compare instances within a given bucket.
I tried to change the prime value in `hasCode()` to spread instances differently into the buckets, and saw that `contains()` still sometimes returned a wrong result, but not for the same previously failing value.
It also seems that this value was then correctly identified as being outwith the set; I therefore suspect something is wrong with the equality check rather than the hashing, but I may be wrong...

I'm at a total loss here, and out of ideas.  Can anyone shed light on this at all?

----- edit -----
**some clarifications:**

- `i1` & `i2` are never updated after construction for the instances that were added to the set (though they are sometimes updated, elsewhere in the code, for other instances of that same class);
- the set is potentially quite large (i.e. can reach nearly 15K entries) and I wonder if the issue could be linked to this (bucket overflow, e.g.?).

Comment: Is it possible you are modifying the values of `i1` and `i2` for objects already contained in your HashSet?

Comment: Are the values of `i1` and `i2` potentially updated *after* the objects are inserted in the set?

Comment: sorry, I should have said, but no they are never updated after construction in this part of the program

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that shows `contains()` returning true when it should return false. As it stands, I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: @J.Doe: You say the values are "never updated after construction *in this part of the program*". Are they updated anywhere else? Are you sure that those changes aren't potentially happening after items are added into the set? For example, are you using multiple threads? In that case, it's possible that the root issue is unsafe publication.

Comment: to reword my previous comment, the integer attributes are never updated after construction _for the instances that were added to the set_, though they are sometimes updated, elsewhere in the code, for other instances of that same class.

Comment: Is there inheritance in you code? I don't ilke `obj.getClass() != MySimpleObject.class`, it will not manage subclasses. Using `instanceof` instead.

Comment: `result =result+ prime * result + i1;` but it's better to use `Objects.hashCode()`

Comment: @Daniel Pryden ok I will produce a minimal failing example

Comment: @dehasi it certainly isn't, as `Object`'s implementation of `hashCode()` returns the reference of the instance, and therefore can differ for two instances with identical values (which it shouldn't)

Comment: I meant `Objects.hash()` sorry for misleading.

Comment: Mapreduce is not using hashcode to compute buckets by default. And your algorithm is distributed, so there's not one instance of that set. You need to use a `WritableComparable` type

Comment: I do disagree that `hashCode()` isn't used by Hadoop (i refer to [the javadoc for `WritableComparable`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html): _Note that hashCode() is frequently used in Hadoop to partition keys._); though indeed that problem goes away when I try and reproduce it within a local routine, as opposed to within the `Mapper`.  However it is `java.util.HashSet` that I import so I do believe hash values come from `hashcode()`.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have trouble coming up with a concise reproduction of this bug.

Your code shown looks right.  I think the objects in your collection are being mutated and this fact is obscured to you by other code.

You could debug this by temporarily adding:

1. Add `boolean hashCodeCalled=false` to your class
2. When hashCode() is called, set `hashCodeCalled=true`
3. When a setter is called, and that boolean is `true`, then throw an exception or log the current stack trace

Alternatively,  you could refactor your code such that these instances are immutable and I bet the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks WW, your suggestion led me to fixing the bug, though I am still not sure why/where my instances where being mutated.  Now I make sure that I instantiate a fresh copy of the object to add to the set instead of trusting that `org.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(...)` indeed returns distinct instances each time, and it all works.  I don't like not knowing what's going on though.